# Python Shopify API output formatted datetime string in django template

Tags: python, django, datetime, shopify

Shopify API gives a string in ISO 8601 format for the order.created_at field.

For example: 2016-04-10T16:30:09-04:00

I want to format this and show it directly in a template, so I have tried:

```
{{ order.created_at|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}
```

But nothing displays, and I don't get any errors. I think it is because it is a string and not a datetime object. I don't want to convert it first though in my view.

Comment: Template tags and filters generally don't produce errors, so that's expected behaviour if it's a string. If it's a string, you will need to convert it to a datetime in your view, or else create a custom template tag to receive that string and convert it to a datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what [@ChidG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36538215/python-shopify-api-output-formatted-datetime-string-in-django-template/36636122#comment60681387_36538215) said in his comment, you need to either:

1. Do the modification in your view prior to rendering.
2. [Add a custom](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/) `templatetag` that takes this string and does it for you.
   Ie, `{{ order.created_at|shopify_date|date:'Y-m-d H:i' }}`

If you really insist on not doing the first, then the second is your only other hope.